# 403 Forbidden if the word "union" is found in url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I noticed that if the word "union" is found/added on a url in my site, I'm getting a 403 forbidden error.

[Here's a snapshot of an ajax (getjson) url with "union" added as GET variable:](http://screencast.com/t/PsCfC6PRrc)
Now, if you alter the word "union" like "unsion" I'm getting a response but if the word "union" is in place and readable like "xxunionxx" the response is still forbidden.

My site runs on CI (CodeIgniter) Framework. I wonder if there's a filtering done over my server?

Thanks!

Comment: if you run `php -v` on your server, do you see any line about "suhosin"?

Comment: It might be your hosting company blocking SQL keywords from URLs to avoid injection attacks. (I've had to deal with a web host like this)

Comment: Reminds me of good little billy drop table

Comment: it _could_ be the mod security. Add this line to your .htaccess and check what happens: `SecFilterEngine Off`

Comment: @Boundless [Little bobby tables?](http://xkcd.com/327) ;D

Comment: Yup. Most likely [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org) or [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) defending against SQL injection (and being relatively paranoid about it.)

Comment: @JamieTaylor Nah, Bobby's little brother - Billy

Comment: @giorgio, Thanks I tried that but I'm still having the same 403 forbidden error. I tried adding SecFilterScanPOST Off as well.

Comment: @JamieTaylor, I'm sorry but I can't seem to run terminal over my server. Is there an alternative way to run that? that "suhosin" wouldn't show up on phpinfo, would it?

Comment: @VincentEdwardGedariaBinua - I can't remember off the top of my head, it should do. You might have access to `shell_exec()` too, so you could try `echo shell_exec('php -v');`

Comment: @JamieTaylor, Thanks but I still can't. I'm getting the following message: "shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons". I'm on a shared hosting account btw so it could be one reason they did this.

Comment: If you have phpmyadmin you should see a warning after you log in: 'Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to documentation for possible issues.'

Comment: @Delpes, oh then It may not be Suhosin, I'm not having that message. Thanks, I'm trying to contact support too now.

Comment: @VincentEdwardGedariaBinua You could post that as an answer to make it more visible to future googlers

Comment: just deleted the comment and posted it as an answer. thanks @JamieTaylor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help! appreciate it. @MattGibson, right on ModSecurity! so support just disabled the mod_security rules and it's working fine now.